# [SSISDB].[internal].[executable_statistics] is empty

Tags: sql-server, ssis, package, executable

I have several SSIS packages in Visual Studio which run perfectly fine.
These packages have one daaflow inside them, and in the dataflow we have the process of filling the data into the tables.

I expect the `[SSISDB].[internal].[executable_statistics]` get filled, every time I run the packages successfully.
But it is always empty.

P.S. I added the dataflow component (in the control flow) into a sequence container. But still, the `[SSISDB].[internal].[executable_statistics]` is empty after the successful execution of the packages.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked [SSISDB].[catalog].[executable_statistics] ?

Comment: @jayvee I have no shema called [caalog]. I only have one schema and that is [internal]